# Tensorflow: How can I calculate Accuracy of CNN model when label is integer index or Class id

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm Testing a `CNN` model which classifies Korean Alphabet Hangul.
I found that the accuracy of my model `shows 1.0` sometimes.

So, I want to know what is the problem

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, labels=input_labels))
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logit,1),input_labels)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

The label of my data is `int64` type class id which covers `[0~2349]`

I want to know it is the correct calculation of accuracy of the model.

Comment: maybe try `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logit,1),tf.argmax(input_labels,1))`

Comment: Probably I can't. Because input_label is not one-hot vector. It is int64 data which is class id. It same as index of one-hot vector. Thanks your asnwer.